# How to create section header listing like whatsapp?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I'm developing chat application and i've already design dummy chat history.But i'm stuck at how to group messages according to it's date and when we scroll it down,date indicator stick at the top position just like whats app. can you just show me the way, how can i achieve that? I've attached some screenshot below to elaborate my question.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: See this image]

Put your header in your custom lisview adapter layout and check everytime your current message date and previous message date. If date is same then hide your header otherwise show your header. See below:

```
 holder.tvDate.setText(chatMessage.getDate());
    if (position > 0) {
        if (chatMessages.get(position).getDate().equalsIgnoreCase(chatMessages.get(position - 1).getDate())) {
            holder.header.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    } else {
        holder.header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: Are you used recyclerview to show the above list? I have used recyclerview but it failed to show the datetime

Comment: I have used listview at that time. But you can also achieve this in recyclerview.

Comment: Ihave used recyclerview, but it failed to sho the datetime view. Did u did like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67058427/failed-to-show-the-grouping-date-view-for-the-chat-messages-in-the-recyclerview/67124150#67124150

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Just add a header view to your ListView

```
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText("Hello. I'm a header view");

listView.addHeaderView(textView);
```

for more details- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)

**Update:**

By far the simplest way to do this is to embed the date header view in every item. Then, all you need to do in bindView is compare the previous row's date to this row's date, and hide the date if it's the same. Something like this:

```
String thisDate = cursor.getString(dateIndex);
String prevDate = null;

// get previous item's date, for comparison
if (cursor.getPosition() > 0 && cursor.moveToPrevious()) {
    prevDate = cursor.getString(dateIndex);
    cursor.moveToNext();
}

// enable section heading if it's the first one, or 
// different from the previous one
if (prevDate == null || !prevDate.equals(thisDate)) {
    dateSectionHeaderView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    dateSectionHeaderView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: as you can see in above screenshot , there is more than one header Yesterday , Today and list view contain only one header @saurav