# Failed to show the grouping date view for the chat messages in the recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

How can I make the grouping and show the date view in my app. I am using recyclerview and java to show this messages

Structure:

```
   --------- **12-04-2021** ----------

--Leftsidemessage--
          ----rightsidemessgae----
--Leftsidemessage--
          ----rightsidemessgae----
--Leftsidemessage--
          ----rightsidemessgae----

    --------- **13-04-2021** ----------
--Leftsidemessage--
          ----rightsidemessgae----
--Leftsidemessage--
          ----rightsidemessgae----
--Leftsidemessage--
          ----rightsidemessgae----
```

The above is the message structure. I can able to show the rightside and leftside messages by the below code, But it failed to show the datetime view in my app.

Here how can I group and show the messages under a particular days message.

My Chat adapter code is here.

```
 @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            Message message = (Message) msgDtoList.get(position);
            if (minemsg) {
                // If the current user is the sender of the message
                return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT;
            }
            if (!minemsg) {
                // If some other user sent the message
                return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED;
            }
    
            if (message.getmSentTime() != "") { // here the message senttime is always print inside this condition. But failed to show the view in the app.
                return DATE_VIEW_TYPE;
            }
    
            return 0;
        }
     @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view;
    
            if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.sender_message_layout, parent, false);
                return new SenderMessageHolder(view);
    
            }
            if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.receiver_message_layout, parent, false);
                return new ReceiverMessageHolder(view);
            }
    
            if (viewType == DATE_VIEW_TYPE) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.date_view, parent, false);
                return new DateViewHolder(view);
            }
    
            return null;
        }

 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message message = (Message) msgDtoList.get(position);

        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT:
                populateSentViewHolder(holder, position);
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
                populateReceivedViewHolder(holder, position);
                break;

            case DATE_VIEW_TYPE:
                populateDateViewHolder(holder, position);
                break;
        }
    }
```

My Chat fragment:

```
  @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View v, @Nullable Bundle b) {
        super.onViewCreated(v, b);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        int newMsgPosition = mAdapter.getItemCount();
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As `minemsg` is either true or false, the code returning `DATE_VIEW_TYPE` would never be reached.  i.e., follow this pseudo-code:

```
boolean minemsg = true;
if (minemsg)
{
  return;
}
if (!minemsg)
{
  return;
}
// anything after this would never be reached!, as minemsg is either true or false.
```

Its not clear from your question what `minemsg` is, please try changing the order of evaluation as follows:

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Message message = (Message) msgDtoList.get(position);
        
        // check for date record first
        if (message.getmSentTime() != "") { // here the message senttime is always print inside this condition. But failed to show the view in the app.
            return DATE_VIEW_TYPE;
        }

        if (minemsg) {
            // If the current user is the sender of the message
            return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT;
        }
        if (!minemsg) {
            // If some other user sent the message
            return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED;
        }

        
        return 0;
    }
```

EDIT: After reading your comments below, your problems are much deeper, you're trying to display a single `ArrayList` of messages with section/group headers.

This is beyond the scope of the question you asked, and appears to already have answers, e.g.:

[How to implement RecyclerView with section header depending on category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907711/how-to-implement-recyclerview-with-section-header-depending-on-category)

Comment: minemsg is the sender id equals the message sender id. How can I group the messages according to the dates and show the date view using this

Comment: Why the date record first can you elaborate? The date is there for all the messages.

Comment: I don't know your data, you tell me how you can look at a Message record and determine if its a LEFT, RIGHT, or DATE record?  As shown in the pseudo-code, a boolean test will either pass or fail, i.e. `minemsg` is either true or false, there isn't a 3rd condition

Comment: It is the chat screen get the message for the sender and receiver with the timestamp. Note: After setting the date as you mentioned, I can't able to see the left and rightside messages. {"response":{"senderid": "myid", "id": "chat_id", "msg": "hai', "timestamp":"date with time"}{"senderid": "otheruserid", "id": "chat_id", "msg": "hai', "timestamp":"date with time"}}}

Comment: Are you mentioning does I need to change the entire view according to the recyclerview with section header?

Comment: I think there is no new update for this sectionrecyclerview after 2016. Last version is 1.0.4, Is it workout as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            Message message = (Message) msgDtoList.get(position);
    
            // Since message can either be "mine" or "not mine" lets check the sent time first, and return the DATE_VIEW_TYPE to avoid dead code
            if (message.getmSentTime() != "") { // here the message senttime is always print inside this condition. But failed to show the view in the app.
                return DATE_VIEW_TYPE;
            }

            if (minemsg) {
                // If the current user is the sender of the message
                return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT;
            }
            if (!minemsg) {
                // If some other user sent the message
                return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED;
            }
            // Everything below is "dead, unreachable code" due to booleans being either true or false
    
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: After setting the date as you mentioned in the above, I can't able to see the left and rightside messages.

Comment: So, are all of the views of the `DATE_VIEW_TYPE` then? If yes - you need to debug this, as unreachable code (date_view type) wasn't your only problem.

Comment: Yes, for every message the date will be there.

Comment: I didn't ask you if the date will be there. I asked whether all views are of the `DATE_VIEW_TYPE` type. Basically asking about this `message.getmSentTime()` thing and whether it's always empty or not.

Comment: If message.getmsenttime is always has a value(i.e) if there is messages available in the chat it always not null

Comment: In this chat room it always has value